# UPDATE table with another table data

Tags: postgresql, update, postgis, greatest-n-per-group

I want to update the table car_check field fencing.(total 40 rows).I also use postgis function.
I think it's a little difficult.Any suggestions?

```
The code is the first carid example.

UPDATE car_check 
set fencing=ST_Contains
from (
SELECT ST_Contains(ST_AsText('01030000..'),
'POINT(23.912784 120.99178)') 
)as foo
where carid='AD-5487' and cargroupid='1'
```

[image]

Comment: Could you tell what do you want to achieve, what is not working?

Comment: To update all car_check table field fencing,the picture is my first sql

Comment: Do you get an error or something?

Comment: The code is correct.But it just can write the first row on fencing field.I want to do the code which can write the all rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this untangled version to update *all* rows of `char_check`:

```
UPDATE car_check c
SET    fencing = ST_Contains(u.geom, ST_MakePoint(t.lat::float8, t.lng::float8))
FROM   test t
      ,rule r
JOIN   (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (polyname)
          polyname, geom
   FROM   unknown_table
   ORDER  BY polyname, version DESC
    ) u USING (polyname)
WHERE  t.id = c.carid
AND    r.cargroupid = c.cargroupid
```

#### Major points

- Use the simpler [`ST_MakePoint`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html) to construct a point geometry from numeric input.
- You do not need `ST_AsText()` at all, since your column `geom` is of type geometry already.
- Fastest and simplest way to get the geometry for the *biggest version* per `polyname` in table `unknown_table` is to use `DISTINCT ON`, which is a Postgres extension of the SQL standard. More details in this related answer:
  [How do I efficiently get "the most recent corresponding row"?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49540/how-do-i-efficiently-get-the-most-recent-corresponding-row/49555#49555)
- In reference to the currently accepted but invalid answer: the concatenation operator in Postgres (and standard SQL) is `||` (not `+`)

Comment: Wow,it's very helpful to me.

Comment: `t.log::float8, t.lat::float8` have to upside down

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to join the tables you are trying to update from. I think the query will need to be converted to this:

```
UPDATE car_check 
set fencing=foo.ST_Contains
from (
SELECT ST_Contains(ST_AsText(p.geom),
ST_GeomFromText('POINT(' || to_char(t.lat, '9999.999999') || ' ' || to_char(t.log, '9999.999999') || ')') AS ST_Contains, cc.carid, cc.cargroupid
FROM test t INNER JOIN car_check cc ON t.id = cc.carid
INNER JOIN rule r ON cc.cargroupid = r.cargroupid
INNER JOIN poly p ON r.polyname = p.polyname
WHERE p.poly_version = (SELECT MAX(p1.poly_version) FROM poly p1 WHERE p1.polyname = p.polyname))as foo 
INNER JOIN car_check 
ON foo.carid = car_check.carid AND foo.cargroupid = car_check.cargroupid
where carid='AD-5487' and cargroupid='1'
```

(I have no idea how your last table is called. The name is cut off from the picture. I called it poly in my statement. Fix it in yours)

Comment: `parse error - invalid geometry
LINE 5: 'POINT(t.lat, t.log)') AS ST_Contains, cc.carid, cc.cargroup...
        ^
HINT:  "POINT(t." <-- parse error at position 8 within geometry`

Comment: `where carid='AD-5487' and cargroupid='1'` , I want it to update to all rows.

Comment: see my updated answer. For some reason I left the single quotes from your original query. They do not need to be there

Comment: go ahead and remove the last where clause. I left it there, as I thought you are interested in those records only

Comment: try this one. BTW, it will help if you could provide a SQL Fiddle with a sample data.

Comment: +1 for the effort of translating paint to sql. :) But @AlexYu: why is this answer accepted? The syntax is invalid.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: thanks for pointing out about the string concatenation. got mixed it with SQL Server