# Nearest value for each foreign key

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, window-functions, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with a primary key, timestamp, value, foreign key. I would like to find the nearest value to a timestamp for each of the foreign keys in a list.

Unfortunately, the gap from the given timestamp to the first value timestamp for one foreign key may be many times this gap for another FK. I've had a go doing something like this, but it only gives me one row, rather than one row per fk.

```
SELECT *
FROM   data_item
WHERE  fk_fc_id IN (35246,35247) 
AND    di_timestamp > '2013-11-01 00:00:00'
ORDER  BY di_timestamp ASC
LIMIT  1;
```

It's like I need to take the limit on a per FK basis, but can't work out how to do that.

Comment: "nearest value to a timestamp" meaning immediately after, or immediately before too?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) to achieve your goal.  `lag()` and `lead()` are ones which can help you in a query like

```
SELECT lag(di_timestamp) OVER ordering, lead(di_timestamp) OVER ordering
  FROM data_item
 WHERE fk_fc_id IN (35246,35247)
WINDOW ordering AS (ORDER BY di_timestamp 
                    RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW);
```

This will return the previous and the next timestamps, if there is any.

Comment: No that won't work. I've realised I wrote the query down wrongly, it should have been this, SELECT * FROM data_item WHERE fk_fc_id IN (35246,35247) and di_timestamp > '2013-11-01 00:00:00' order by di_timestamp asc limit 1; but it still won't work.

Comment: Probably I did not understand you correctly.  Do you want to follow the FK to the referenced table?  Or what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is I want the first record after a given date for a list of individual foreign keys. This should return the same number of rows as foreign keys.

Comment: @James If the query is wrong, **edit the original question to fix it**. (I think you need to add some sample data and expected results to better explain what you want, too).

Comment: Will `LEAD` actually work as expected when the range is `BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`? Shouldn't the range include at least one row following the current one?

Answer (score 1):

To get *one* row for each `fk_fc_id` listed that comes after the given timestamp and is closest to it .. best use [**`DISTINCT ON`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT), a Postgres-specific extension of the standard SQL `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (fk_fc_id)
       *
FROM   data_item
WHERE  fk_fc_id IN (35246,35247)
AND    di_timestamp > '2013-11-01 00:00:00' 
ORDER  BY fk_fc_id, di_timestamp;
```

If you need the result sorted by `di_timestamp`, wrap it in a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (fk_fc_id)
          *
   FROM   data_item
   WHERE  fk_fc_id IN (35246,35247)
   AND    di_timestamp > '2013-11-01 00:00:00' 
   ORDER  BY fk_fc_id, di_timestamp
   ) sub
ORDER  BY di_timestamp;
```

Or you could use the [window function `row_number()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) (probably slower, standard SQL):

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY fk_fc_id
                                ORDER BY di_timestamp) AS rn
   FROM   data_item
   WHERE  fk_fc_id IN (35246,35247)
   AND    di_timestamp > '2013-11-01 00:00:00' 
   ORDER  BY fk_fc_id, di_timestamp;
  ) sub
WHERE  rn = 1
ORDER  BY di_timestamp;
```

There are more ways. More details in this related answer:
[How do I efficiently get "the most recent corresponding row"?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49540/how-do-i-efficiently-get-the-most-recent-corresponding-row/49555#49555)

Even more under this related question on SO:
[Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)