# optimization of expensive subquery

Tags: postgresql, performance, optimization, subquery, greatest-n-per-group, query-performance

The following query gets the last report (where latitude and longitude and secs are `<> 0`) associated with the specified units:

```
SELECT 
    reports.* 
FROM
    reports 
    INNER JOIN 
        units 
        ON units.id = reports.unit_id 
WHERE 
    reports.unit_id IN (1111, 1112, 1113) 
    AND 
    (
        reports.id = 
        (
            SELECT reports.id 
            FROM reports
            WHERE reports.unit_id = units.id
            AND
            reports.time_secs != 0
            AND 
            reports.latitude != 0.0
            AND
            reports.longitude != 0.0
            ORDER BY time desc
            LIMIT 1
        )
    )
```

This query took several minutes to run, and I was wondering if there is an optimization I can do to it.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using "= 0" and not "!= 0"? AS far as I understood you wanted to find records, where all 3 values are 0 ?

Comment: @SaschaRambeaud I meant all 3 values are not 0, sorry

Comment: Ok, fixed below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be *considerably* simpler and faster with [`DISTINCT ON`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (r.unit_id)
       r.* 
FROM   reports r
JOIN   units   u ON u.id = r.unit_id 
WHERE  r.unit_id IN (1111, 1112, 1113) 
AND    r.time_secs <> 0
AND    r.latitude  <> 0.0
AND    r.longitude <> 0.0
ORDER  BY r.unit_id, r.time DESC;
```

More explanation in these related answers:
[How do I efficiently get "the most recent corresponding row"?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49540/how-do-i-efficiently-get-the-most-recent-corresponding-row/49555#49555)
[Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564) (on SO)

Minor detail: the standard SQL operator for "is not equal" is `<>`. Use that rather than `!=` (which is accepted as well in Postgres).

The only possible purpose of joining to the table **`units`** in this query is to verify that one or more related rows exist. If `reports.unit_id` is bound to `unit.id` by foreign key (as the naming suggests) referential integrity is guaranteed and you can drop the table `unit` from the query completely. Just add: `unit_id IS NOT NULL`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (unit_id) * 
FROM   reports
WHERE  unit_id IN (1111, 1112, 1113) 
AND    time_secs <> 0
AND    latitude  <> 0.0
AND    longitude <> 0.0
AND    unit_id IS NOT NULL
ORDER  BY unit_id, time DESC;
```

Comment: Did you verify that this computes faster? I cannot currently test it with Postgres, but on SQL-Server i frequently found that over(partition by..) is a lot faster than group by. Your code definitely looks nicer, though, but in my defense i can only say i didn't know about DISTINCT ON, seems to be postgreSQL specific.

Comment: @SaschaRambeaud: Description *and* example seem to indicate "all three columns <> 0". And yes, I verified my assertion about performance (on multiple occasions). [Details in the second linked answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Comment: Thanks, good to know in case i ever have to work with PostgreSQL :). (I only checked out your first link earlier, sorry)

Answer (score 2):

```
  WITH T1 as (SELECT 
            reports.* , row_number() over (partition by unit_id order by reports.time DESC) as RN
        FROM
            reports 
            INNER JOIN 
                units 
                ON units.id = reports.unit_id
        WHERE 
        reports.unit_id IN (1111, 1112, 1113) AND
        reports.time_secs <> 0 AND 
        reports.latitude <> 0.0 AND
        reports.longitude <> 0.0)
)
    SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: I am using postgresql.

Comment: Added an example using a window function. CTE, so you can filter for row_number() results. I don't know if you need to inner join to units because there can be unit_id values that have no match in the units table, because otherwise the join seems unnecessary?

Comment: Also instead of select * from the CTE, you'd need to select the desired columns, to avoid getting the row number in results.