# Optimizing large database query (25+ million rows, using max() and GROUP BY)

Tags: postgresql, index, performance, query-performance

I'm using Postgres 9.3.5 and I have a large table in the database, currently it has over 25 million rows and it tends to get even larger rapidly. I'm trying to select specific rows (all `unit_id`s with only latest `unit_timestamp` for each of them) with a simple query like:

```
SELECT unit_id, max(unit_timestamp) AS latest_timestamp FROM all_units GROUP BY unit_id;
```

Without any index, this query takes about 35 seconds to execute. With an index defined (`CREATE INDEX partial_idx ON all_units (unit_id, unit_timestamp DESC);`) the query time is shortened to around (only) 19 seconds.

I wonder if it will ever be possible to execute my query in even less time (like just few seconds) and if so, what steps should I take in order to optimize it even further?

My table structure dump looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "all_units" (
"unit_id" int4 NOT NULL,
"unit_timestamp" timestamp(6) NOT NULL,
"lon" float4,
"lat" float4,
"speed" float4,
"status" varchar(255) COLLATE "default"
)
ALTER TABLE "all_units" ADD PRIMARY KEY ("unit_id", "unit_timestamp");
```

The `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` follows:

```
QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HashAggregate  (cost=663998.38..664069.73 rows=7135 width=12) (actual time=84715.050..84732.021 rows=11094 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=192 read=286819
  ->  Seq Scan on ais_sorted  (cost=0.00..538335.92 rows=25132492 width=12) (actual time=0.608..41264.196 rows=25132492 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=192 read=286819
Total runtime: 84746.501 ms
```

and my psql settings on server look like this:

```
                name                 |  context   |  min_val  |   max_val    |                boot_val
-------------------------------------+------------+-----------+--------------+-----------------------------------------
 allow_system_table_mods             | postmaster |           |              | off
 application_name                    | user       |           |              |
 archive_command                     | sighup     |           |              |
 archive_mode                        | postmaster |           |              | off
 archive_timeout                     | sighup     | 0         | 1073741823   | 0
 array_nulls                         | user       |           |              | on
 authentication_timeout              | sighup     | 1         | 600          | 60
 autovacuum                          | sighup     |           |              | on
 autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor     | sighup     | 0         | 100          | 0.1
 autovacuum_analyze_threshold        | sighup     | 0         | 2147483647   | 50
 autovacuum_freeze_max_age           | postmaster | 100000000 | 2000000000   | 200000000
 autovacuum_max_workers              | postmaster | 1         | 8388607      | 3
 autovacuum_multixact_freeze_max_age | postmaster | 10000000  | 2000000000   | 400000000
 autovacuum_naptime                  | sighup     | 1         | 2147483      | 60
 autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay        | sighup     | -1        | 100          | 20
 autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit        | sighup     | -1        | 10000        | -1
 autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor      | sighup     | 0         | 100          | 0.2
 autovacuum_vacuum_threshold         | sighup     | 0         | 2147483647   | 50
 backslash_quote                     | user       |           |              | safe_encoding
 bgwriter_delay                      | sighup     | 10        | 10000        | 200
 bgwriter_lru_maxpages               | sighup     | 0         | 1000         | 100
 bgwriter_lru_multiplier             | sighup     | 0         | 10           | 2
 block_size                          | internal   | 8192      | 8192         | 8192
 bonjour                             | postmaster |           |              | off
 bonjour_name                        | postmaster |           |              |
 bytea_output                        | user       |           |              | hex
 check_function_bodies               | user       |           |              | on
 checkpoint_completion_target        | sighup     | 0         | 1            | 0.5
 checkpoint_segments                 | sighup     | 1         | 2147483647   | 3
 checkpoint_timeout                  | sighup     | 30        | 3600         | 300
 checkpoint_warning                  | sighup     | 0         | 2147483647   | 30
 client_encoding                     | user       |           |              | SQL_ASCII
 client_min_messages                 | user       |           |              | notice
 commit_delay                        | superuser  | 0         | 100000       | 0
 commit_siblings                     | user       | 0         | 1000         | 5
 config_file                         | postmaster |           |              |
 constraint_exclusion                | user       |           |              | partition
 cpu_index_tuple_cost                | user       | 0         | 1.79769e+308 | 0.005
 cpu_operator_cost                   | user       | 0         | 1.79769e+308 | 0.0025
 cpu_tuple_cost                      | user       | 0         | 1.79769e+308 | 0.01
 cursor_tuple_fraction               | user       | 0         | 1            | 0.1
 data_checksums                      | internal   |           |              | off
 data_directory                      | postmaster |           |              |
 DateStyle                           | user       |           |              | ISO, MDY
 db_user_namespace                   | sighup     |           |              | off
 deadlock_timeout                    | superuser  | 1         | 2147483647   | 1000
 debug_assertions                    | user       |           |              | off
 debug_pretty_print                  | user       |           |              | on
 debug_print_parse                   | user       |           |              | off
 debug_print_plan                    | user       |           |              | off
 debug_print_rewritten               | user       |           |              | off
 default_statistics_target           | user       | 1         | 10000        | 100
 default_tablespace                  | user       |           |              |
 default_text_search_config          | user       |           |              | pg_catalog.simple
 default_transaction_deferrable      | user       |           |              | off
 default_transaction_isolation       | user       |           |              | read committed
 default_transaction_read_only       | user       |           |              | off
 default_with_oids                   | user       |           |              | off
 dynamic_library_path                | superuser  |           |              | $libdir
 effective_cache_size                | user       | 1         | 2147483647   | 16384
 effective_io_concurrency            | user       | 0         | 1000         | 1
 enable_bitmapscan                   | user       |           |              | on
 enable_hashagg                      | user       |           |              | on
 enable_hashjoin                     | user       |           |              | on
 enable_indexonlyscan                | user       |           |              | on
 enable_indexscan                    | user       |           |              | on
 enable_material                     | user       |           |              | on
 enable_mergejoin                    | user       |           |              | on
 enable_nestloop                     | user       |           |              | on
 enable_seqscan                      | user       |           |              | on
 enable_sort                         | user       |           |              | on
 enable_tidscan                      | user       |           |              | on
 escape_string_warning               | user       |           |              | on
 event_source                        | postmaster |           |              | PostgreSQL
 exit_on_error                       | user       |           |              | off
 external_pid_file                   | postmaster |           |              |
 extra_float_digits                  | user       | -15       | 3            | 0
 from_collapse_limit                 | user       | 1         | 2147483647   | 8
 fsync                               | sighup     |           |              | on
 full_page_writes                    | sighup     |           |              | on
 geqo                                | user       |           |              | on
 geqo_effort                         | user       | 1         | 10           | 5
 geqo_generations                    | user       | 0         | 2147483647   | 0
 geqo_pool_size                      | user       | 0         | 2147483647   | 0
 geqo_seed                           | user       | 0         | 1            | 0
 geqo_selection_bias                 | user       | 1.5       | 2            | 2
 geqo_threshold                      | user       | 2         | 2147483647   | 12
 gin_fuzzy_search_limit              | user       | 0         | 2147483647   | 0
 hba_file                            | postmaster |           |              |
 hot_standby                         | postmaster |           |              | off
 hot_standby_feedback                | sighup     |           |              | off
 ident_file                          | postmaster |           |              |
 ignore_checksum_failure             | superuser  |           |              | off
 ignore_system_indexes               | backend    |           |              | off
 integer_datetimes                   | internal   |           |              | on
 IntervalStyle                       | user       |           |              | postgres
 join_collapse_limit                 | user       | 1         | 2147483647   | 8
 krb_caseins_users                   | sighup     |           |              | off
 krb_server_keyfile                  | sighup     |           |              | FILE:/etc/postgresql-common/krb5.keytab
 krb_srvname                         | sighup     |           |              | postgres
 lc_collate                          | internal   |           |              | C
 lc_ctype                            | internal   |           |              | C
 lc_messages                         | superuser  |           |              |
 lc_monetary                         | user       |           |              | C
 lc_numeric                          | user       |           |              | C
 lc_time                             | user       |           |              | C
 listen_addresses                    | postmaster |           |              | localhost
 lo_compat_privileges                | superuser  |           |              | off
 local_preload_libraries             | backend    |           |              |
 lock_timeout                        | user       | 0         | 2147483647   | 0
 log_autovacuum_min_duration         | sighup     | -1        | 2147483647   | -1
 log_checkpoints                     | sighup     |           |              | off
 log_connections                     | backend    |           |              | off
 log_destination                     | sighup     |           |              | stderr
 log_directory                       | sighup     |           |              | pg_log
 log_disconnections                  | backend    |           |              | off
 log_duration                        | superuser  |           |              | off
 log_error_verbosity                 | superuser  |           |              | default
 log_executor_stats                  | superuser  |           |              | off
 log_file_mode                       | sighup     | 0         | 511          | 384
 log_filename                        | sighup     |           |              | postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log
 log_hostname                        | sighup     |           |              | off
 log_line_prefix                     | sighup     |           |              |
 log_lock_waits                      | superuser  |           |              | off
 log_min_duration_statement          | superuser  | -1        | 2147483647   | -1
 log_min_error_statement             | superuser  |           |              | error
 log_min_messages                    | superuser  |           |              | warning
 log_parser_stats                    | superuser  |           |              | off
 log_planner_stats                   | superuser  |           |              | off
 log_rotation_age                    | sighup     | 0         | 35791394     | 1440
 log_rotation_size                   | sighup     | 0         | 2097151      | 10240
 log_statement                       | superuser  |           |              | none
 log_statement_stats                 | superuser  |           |              | off
 log_temp_files                      | superuser  | -1        | 2147483647   | -1
 log_timezone                        | sighup     |           |              | GMT
 log_truncate_on_rotation            | sighup     |           |              | off
 logging_collector                   | postmaster |           |              | off
 maintenance_work_mem                | user       | 1024      | 2147483647   | 16384
 max_connections                     | postmaster | 1         | 8388607      | 100
 max_files_per_process               | postmaster | 25        | 2147483647   | 1000
 max_function_args                   | internal   | 100       | 100          | 100
 max_identifier_length               | internal   | 63        | 63           | 63
 max_index_keys                      | internal   | 32        | 32           | 32
 max_locks_per_transaction           | postmaster | 10        | 2147483647   | 64
 max_pred_locks_per_transaction      | postmaster | 10        | 2147483647   | 64
 max_prepared_transactions           | postmaster | 0         | 8388607      | 0
 max_stack_depth                     | superuser  | 100       | 2147483647   | 100
 max_standby_archive_delay           | sighup     | -1        | 2147483647   | 30000
 max_standby_streaming_delay         | sighup     | -1        | 2147483647   | 30000
 max_wal_senders                     | postmaster | 0         | 8388607      | 0
 password_encryption                 | user       |           |              | on
 port                                | postmaster | 1         | 65535        | 5432
 post_auth_delay                     | backend    | 0         | 2147         | 0
 pre_auth_delay                      | sighup     | 0         | 60           | 0
 quote_all_identifiers               | user       |           |              | off
 random_page_cost                    | user       | 0         | 1.79769e+308 | 4
 restart_after_crash                 | sighup     |           |              | on
 search_path                         | user       |           |              | "$user",public
 segment_size                        | internal   | 131072    | 131072       | 131072
 seq_page_cost                       | user       | 0         | 1.79769e+308 | 1
 server_encoding                     | internal   |           |              | SQL_ASCII
 server_version                      | internal   |           |              | 9.3.5
 server_version_num                  | internal   | 90305     | 90305        | 90305
 session_replication_role            | superuser  |           |              | origin
 shared_buffers                      | postmaster | 16        | 1073741823   | 1024
 shared_preload_libraries            | postmaster |           |              |
 sql_inheritance                     | user       |           |              | on
 ssl                                 | postmaster |           |              | off
 ssl_ca_file                         | postmaster |           |              |
 ssl_cert_file                       | postmaster |           |              | server.crt
 ssl_ciphers                         | postmaster |           |              | DEFAULT:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:@STRENGTH
 ssl_crl_file                        | postmaster |           |              |
 ssl_key_file                        | postmaster |           |              | server.key
 ssl_renegotiation_limit             | user       | 0         | 2147483647   | 524288
 standard_conforming_strings         | user       |           |              | on
 statement_timeout                   | user       | 0         | 2147483647   | 0
 stats_temp_directory                | sighup     |           |              | pg_stat_tmp
 superuser_reserved_connections      | postmaster | 0         | 8388607      | 3
 synchronize_seqscans                | user       |           |              | on
 synchronous_commit                  | user       |           |              | on
 synchronous_standby_names           | sighup     |           |              |
 syslog_facility                     | sighup     |           |              | local0
 syslog_ident                        | sighup     |           |              | postgres
 tcp_keepalives_count                | user       | 0         | 2147483647   | 0
 tcp_keepalives_idle                 | user       | 0         | 2147483647   | 0
 tcp_keepalives_interval             | user       | 0         | 2147483647   | 0
 temp_buffers                        | user       | 100       | 1073741823   | 1024
 temp_file_limit                     | superuser  | -1        | 2147483647   | -1
 temp_tablespaces                    | user       |           |              |
 TimeZone                            | user       |           |              | GMT
 timezone_abbreviations              | user       |           |              |
 trace_notify                        | user       |           |              | off
 trace_recovery_messages             | sighup     |           |              | log
 trace_sort                          | user       |           |              | off
 track_activities                    | superuser  |           |              | on
 track_activity_query_size           | postmaster | 100       | 102400       | 1024
 track_counts                        | superuser  |           |              | on
 track_functions                     | superuser  |           |              | none
 track_io_timing                     | superuser  |           |              | off
 transaction_deferrable              | user       |           |              | off
 transaction_isolation               | user       |           |              | default
 transaction_read_only               | user       |           |              | off
 transform_null_equals               | user       |           |              | off
 unix_socket_directories             | postmaster |           |              | /var/run/postgresql
 unix_socket_group                   | postmaster |           |              |
 unix_socket_permissions             | postmaster | 0         | 511          | 511
 update_process_title                | superuser  |           |              | on
 vacuum_cost_delay                   | user       | 0         | 100          | 0
 vacuum_cost_limit                   | user       | 1         | 10000        | 200
 vacuum_cost_page_dirty              | user       | 0         | 10000        | 20
 vacuum_cost_page_hit                | user       | 0         | 10000        | 1
 vacuum_cost_page_miss               | user       | 0         | 10000        | 10
 vacuum_defer_cleanup_age            | sighup     | 0         | 1000000      | 0
 vacuum_freeze_min_age               | user       | 0         | 1000000000   | 50000000
 vacuum_freeze_table_age             | user       | 0         | 2000000000   | 150000000
 vacuum_multixact_freeze_min_age     | user       | 0         | 1000000000   | 5000000
 vacuum_multixact_freeze_table_age   | user       | 0         | 2000000000   | 150000000
 wal_block_size                      | internal   | 8192      | 8192         | 8192
 wal_buffers                         | postmaster | -1        | 2147483647   | -1
 wal_keep_segments                   | sighup     | 0         | 2147483647   | 0
 wal_level                           | postmaster |           |              | minimal
 wal_receiver_status_interval        | sighup     | 0         | 2147483      | 10
 wal_receiver_timeout                | sighup     | 0         | 2147483647   | 60000
 wal_segment_size                    | internal   | 2048      | 2048         | 2048
 wal_sender_timeout                  | sighup     | 0         | 2147483647   | 60000
 wal_sync_method                     | sighup     |           |              | fdatasync
 wal_writer_delay                    | sighup     | 1         | 10000        | 200
 work_mem                            | user       | 64        | 2147483647   | 1024
 xmlbinary                           | user       |           |              | base64
 xmloption                           | user       |           |              | content
 zero_damaged_pages                  | superuser  |           |              | off
```

Comment: Do you really need ALL unit_ids?Because a WHERE clause would help.

Comment: Unfortunately I do need ALL of them, and to make it even worse, right now I get "only" 11000+ units in return, but in the future I believe there will be 5-10 times more of them.

Comment: Try `SELECT DISTINCT ON (unit_id),unit_timestamp FROM t ORDER BY unit_timestamp DESC` A separate index on unit_timestamp would help.

Comment: is materialized view an option?

Comment: Hm, didn't know about materialized views at all. I will try to create one and see if that would be useful!

Comment: @Mihai, after adding an extra index `CREATE INDEX ts_idx ON all_units (unit_timestamp DESC)` the `DISTINCT ON` query (`SELECT DISTINCT ON (unit_id) unit_id, unit_timestamp FROM all_units ORDER BY unit_id, unit_timestamp DESC`) takes even longer (around 42 seconds), but I have noticed that with those 2 indexes on that table, my original query takes a bit less than usual (around 15 seconds).

Comment: Look here for recursive CTE http://explainextended.com/2009/11/26/postgresql-selecting-records-holding-group-wise-maximum/

Comment: How many distinct units? And do you have a table `unit` listing all of them? Also, what's the content of the column `"status"` and why is it defined `varchar(255)` (which is almost always pointless in Postgres)?

Comment: @Mihai, thanks for the link, I actually found it myself just recently, will definitely read it and try to understand every single word :)   


@ErwinBrandstetter, there are around 11000 distinct units atm, but will be much more of them very soon. And actually there is a table which defines all `unit`s, do you think that JOINing would help in this particular case? The column `status` will be in some way a bunch of unpredictably pointless text, that's why it is defined as `varchar(255)` :)

Comment: Only the first @-reply works in comments. Saw this by chance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Query

Your query is forced to scan the whole table (or the whole index). Every row *could* be another distinct unit. The only way to substantially shorten the process would be a **separate table with all available units** - which would help as long as there are substantially fewer units than entries in `all_units`.
Since you have ~ 11k units (added in comment) for 25M entries, this should definitely help.

Depending on frequencies of values, there are a couple of query techniques to get your result considerably faster:

- recursive CTE
- `JOIN LATERAL`
- correlated subquery

Details in this related answer on SO:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25536748/939860)

Only needing the implicit index of the primary key on `(unit_id, unit_timestamp)`, this query should do the trick, using an implicit `JOIN LATERAL`:

```
SELECT u.unit_id, a.max_ts
FROM unit u
  , (SELECT unit_timestamp AS max_ts
     FROM   all_units
     WHERE  unit_id = u.unit_id
     ORDER  BY unit_timestamp DESC
     LIMIT  1
     ) a;
```

Excludes units without entry in `all_units`, like your original query.
Or a lowly correlated subquery (probably even faster):

```
SELECT u.unit_id
    , (SELECT unit_timestamp
       FROM   all_units
       WHERE  unit_id = u.unit_id
       ORDER  BY unit_timestamp DESC
       LIMIT  1) AS max_ts
FROM unit u;
```

Includes units without entry in `all_units`.

Efficiency depends on the number of entries *per unit*. The more entries, the more potential for one of these queries.

In a **quick local test** with similar tables (500 "units", 1M rows in big table), the query with correlated subqueries was ~ **500x faster** than your original. Index-only scans on the PK index of the big table vs. sequential scan in your original query.

Since your table `tends to get even larger rapidly`, a [materialized view](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-creatematerializedview.html) is probably not an option.

There is also `DISTINCT ON` as another possible query technique, but it's hardly going to be faster than your original query, so *not the answer* you are looking for. Details here:

- [How do I efficiently get "the most recent corresponding row"?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49540/how-do-i-efficiently-get-the-most-recent-corresponding-row/49555#49555)

#### Index

Your `partial_idx`:

```
CREATE INDEX partial_idx ON all_units (unit_id, unit_timestamp DESC);
```

is not in fact a [partial index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-partial.html) and also redundant. Postgres can scan indexes backwards at practically the same speed, the PK serves well. **Drop** this additional index.

#### Table layout

A couple of points for your table definition.

```
CREATE TABLE all_units (
unit_timestamp timestamp,
unit_id int4,
lon     float4,
lat     float4,
speed   float4,
status  varchar(255),   -- might be improved.
PRIMARY KEY (unit_id, unit_timestamp)
);
```

- `timestamp(6)` doesn't make much sense, it's effectively the same as just [`timestamp`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html), which already saves a maximum of 6 fractional digits.
- I switched positions of the first two columns to save 4 bytes of padding, which amounts to ~ 100 MB for 25M rows (exact result depends on `status`). Smaller tables are typically faster for everything.
- If `status` isn't free text, but some kind of standardized note, you could replace it with something a lot cheaper. [More about `varchar(255)` in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24558650/refactor-foreign-key-to-fields/24560486#24560486).

#### Server configuration

You need to configure your server. Most of your settings seem to be conservative defaults. 1 MB on `shared_buffers` or `work_mem` seems **way to low** for an installation with millions of rows. And `random_pare_cost = 4` is to high for any modern system with plenty of RAM. Start with the manual and the Postgres Wiki:

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config.html
- http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server

Comment: For completeness, you should add the `DISTINCT ON` mthod in the list of query techniques for this problem (of course if OP wants to show all rows as he claims, and not just the 2 columns as the code shows)

Comment: @ypercube: For completeness, yes. But it's hardly going to be faster. Not the answer the OP is looking for.

Comment: Could you elaborate how a recursive CTE is going to be faster (or even: how it would solve the problem in the first place - I have never thought about recursive CTEs for a "max" problem)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name_: An rCTE can be used to emulate a *loose index scan*. This is particularly effective for *few* units across *many* rows. Follow [the link I provided](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimizing-group-by-sql-query-to-retrieve-latest-record/25536748#25536748) for details.

Comment: @errata: I would be very interested how the various alternatives perform in your case. Would you mind dropping a comment here with performance for each?

Comment: Does Postegres have something like bitmap index?

Comment: @Mihai: no, it only has a bitmap index _scan_ (that is it generates the bitmap index "on the fly")

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter ALRIGHT! First of all thank you very very much for this elaborated answer, it was extremely helpful, I cannot explain you how much! :) Second, your query (the second one) is AWESOME! The query time is now around **0.2 seconds**!!! :) I tried to play around with the first query also but I didn't manage to resolve the error I got: `invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "u"` in this `WHERE` clause in inner query. Sorry, but I'm not so good with databases myself so I didn't oppress my head with it since the second query helped already a lot.

Comment: What I'm wondering also is does it make a difference if my table is not initially sorted in any way? Would it be even more helpful to sort the table by timestamp and unit_id at all? And regarding the table structure, it was just a `structure dump` option from Navicat, which is probably adding some silly things in the `CREATE TABLE` query, but I will definitely take a look at table structure and try to improve it as much as possible. I am also aware that server config is just out-of-the-box, so there is some space for improvement there also which in the end should make everything even faster :)

Comment: @errata: "Clustering" the table (physically sort rows in table according to an index) often helps performance. But in this case you should see an index only scan mostly, which reads from the index exclusively. Besides, the latest records seem to get written to the end of the table automatically, don't they? More details: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42290/configuring-postgresql-for-read-performance/43142#43142

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter The initial table I have is not sorted in any way, it was just bunch of data randomly imported, so I tried to duplicate it with some sort of ordering and it is just slightly faster. So I will definitely use that one for now, but yeah, when new data comes it will be written in the particular order for sure :) Thanks for helping one more time, it means a lot!