# Retrieving latest record using DISTINCT ON is slow

Tags: postgresql, index, performance, postgresql-9.4, query-performance

Using Postgres 9.4.
I have a table `cartests` with **5.5M** rows. Each row is a car test:

```
\d log.cartests;
             Table "log.cartests"
   Column    |           Type           | Modifiers 
-------------+--------------------------+-----------
 carid       | integer                  | not null
 timestamp   | timestamp with time zone | not null
 exhaust     | varchar                  | 
 brakes      | varchar

 Indexes:
    "cartests_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id, "position", "timestamp")
    "cartests_carid_idx" btree (carid)
    "cartests_timestamp_idx" btree ("timestamp")
```

I need to retrieve the **latest** log for each car.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (carid) carid, timestamp, exhaust, brakes
FROM log.cartests
ORDER BY carid, timestamp DESC;
```

This one takes ~ 6 seconds. Running `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` gives:

> ```
> Unique  (cost=933787.06..961490.34 rows=472 width=16) 
>          (actual time=4951.347..6072.534 rows=476 loops=1)
>   ->  Sort  (cost=933787.06..947638.70 rows=5540656 width=16) 
>             (actual time=4951.345..5782.466 rows=5540656 loops=1)
>         Sort Key: carid, "timestamp"
>         Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 162504kB
>         ->  Seq Scan on cartests  
>             (cost=0.00..123810.56 rows=5540656 width=16)
>             (actual time=0.009..620.988 rows=5540656 loops=1)
> Planning time: 0.107 ms
> Execution time: 6095.598 ms
> ```

Why must it sort if I have an index on both `carid` and `timestamp`?
Is there a better method to use here?

Comment: Indexes are listed above. Added PG9.4 Thx.

Comment: Thank you, you caught a mistake. I will fix it, it is supposed to be carid.

Comment: An index on `(carid, timestamp DESC)` would be better for this query. See asimilar question: [How do I efficiently get “the most recent corresponding row”?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49540/how-do-i-efficiently-get-the-most-recent-corresponding-row)

Comment: And since you are in 9.3+, another question that shows how to rewrite using the `LATERAL` construct: [Optimizing GROUP BY SQL query to retrieve latest record](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimizing-group-by-sql-query-to-retrieve-latest-record/25536748#25536748). It could be eve faster - but it depends I think on the number of distinct `carid` values.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the pointers -- I will experiment and report back with results.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ypercube! Adding the suggested index + using the LATERAL construct got my queries running like lightning.

Answer (score 0):

> Why must it sort if I have an index on both carid and timestamp?
>   Is there a better method to use here?

Because you don't have an index on both carid and timestamp!  You have an index on carid, and a different index on timestamp.  If you want the query to use both, you need an index on (carid, "timestamp") as ypercube mentioned.

Likewise, I'd try switching from the DISTINCT ORDER BY to a GROUP BY, and benchmarking each.

With every tuning question, try writing the query in a few different ways, and compare them against each other - how fast are they, and how much resources do they use?

Comment: While a multicolumn index is superior for the use case, Postgres *can* combine two indexes rather efficiently, too. `GROUP BY` is not very useful to get whole rows.