# Getting an aggregate (here: min) for a group of values

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, greatest-n-per-group

Example table:

```
ID   | value A | value B  
----------------------  
1    |    abc  |   3  
1    |    def  |   5  
1    |    ghi  |   1  
2    |    cba  |   9  
2    |    fed  |   4
```

I want the rows from within any 'ID-group' that has it's minimum within that group in value B.

Wanted result:

```
ID | value A | value B  
----------------------  
1  |    ghi  |   1  
2  |    fed  |   4
```

Anything I tried with group by always fails because of that 'value B'-column and its varying values because I do not want to / cannot aggregate them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I efficiently get "the most recent corresponding row"?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49540/how-do-i-efficiently-get-the-most-recent-corresponding-row)

Comment: Please don't put the DBMS in the title. It's place is in the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select ID, value_A, value_B 
From t where (value_B,ID) in 
(select min(value_B),ID from t group by ID);
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is not correct. If the first line was `1 | abc | 4`, then it would appear in the results of this query.

Comment: sorry mate I didn't get you. It will not get selected since for ID=1 minimum value of VALUE_B is still 1. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: See for yourself: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6e755/1

Comment: well explained. sorry about this..:-)

Comment: No worries. You can either delete the answer or correct it.

Comment: what abt this new answer

Comment: Why are you concatenating the columns as strings? Most (all?) DBMSes should support `... where (ID, value_B) in (select ID, min(value_B) ...`

Comment: hmmm...let me correct it...

Comment: Looks all right now.

Comment: Thank you very much, i worked for my problem and solved it!! Quick and good help. Should I mark this Question somehow solved?

Comment: @user66529 You can accept any one of the answers as "most helpful". This marks your question solved. But please edit the question ans state the DBMS you are using (mySQL, Postgres, Oracle, ...).

Comment: cheers, done so.

Comment: @Gerd: No offense to vinpin trying to get it right, but I don't see why you accepted the least useful answer. No explanation here, and performance for `IN (subselect)` is typically worse than for `DISTINCT ON` or `row_number()` (or other variants discussed in the duplicate question).

Answer (score 3):

Postgres has `distinct on` that does just what you are looking for:

```
select distinct on (id) id, value_a, value_b
from t
order by id, value_b;
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6e755/7)

You haven't specified what you would like to see when the are multiple values of `value_b` for an `id` though.

Comment: I always forget about this very handy `distinct on` syntax that PostgreSQL has! Coming from an Oracle background, I always solve these type of queries using window functions; using `rank()` or `dense_rank()` in the query of my answer will solve the last point: what to do with multiple values.

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem that the OP hasn't specified how he wants ties broken though ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can do a `GROUP BY` to get the minimum value of `value_B` and then join back with the main table. Something like this.

```
select table1.ID, table1.value_A, table1.value_B 
From table1 inner join 
(select id,min(value_B) value_B from table1 group by ID) t1
on table1.id = t1.id and table1.value_B = t1.value_B;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/21892/5)

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. I was too lazy to try as the other answer was shorter to type... Guess your code should have done it too!

Comment: Not an issue. As long your question gets answered, it's all good.

Answer (score 2):

In PostgreSQL 8.4+ or any other DBMS that supports windowing functions, the following approach will also work, and will probably be faster on large tables because the database can answer the query with a single scan of the main table (rather than aggregating on the first scan and then querying the main table again for matching rows):

```
select ID, value_A, value_B
from (
  select t.*, row_number() over (partition by ID order by value_B) as r
  from table1 t
) x
where r = 1;
```