# Aggregate function to return any (first) encountered value

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

How do I tell PostgreSQL to return first encountered value instead of an aggregate column?

```
                          Table "public.cache"
  Column   |  Type   | Modifiers | Storage | Stats target | Description 
-----------+---------+-----------+---------+--------------+-------------
 user_id   | integer |           | plain   |              | 
 object_id | integer |           | plain   |              | 
 data      | integer |           | plain   |              | 
 data2     | boolean |           | plain   |              | 
Indexes:
    "cache_object_id_user_id_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (object_id, user_id)
    "cache_user_id_object_id_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (user_id, object_id)
Has OIDs: no
```

Query grouping by object_id and data2 will make hash aggregate, what I want to avoid.

```
SELECT object_id, data2 FROM cache GROUP BY object_id, data2;
```

I found `bool_or()` but it will scan all values in bad case.

```
SELECT object_id, bool_or(data2) FROM cache GROUP BY object_id;
```

Moreover, there is no such function for any datatype. What I want to do is to get any of the values from data2 column so that engine don't have to iterate all rows.

What about data column which is integer?

Comment: Ypercube's answer covers it. Also related: [Best performance in sampling repeated value from a grouped column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36134657/best-performance-in-sampling-repeated-value-from-a-grouped-column)

Answer (score 7):

There are various ways to do this, with different performance, depending on the distribution of data (number of distinct `object_id` values, etc).

The easiest query to write - but not necessary the most efficient, is of course using an aggregate, `MIN()` or `MAX()`:

```
SELECT object_id, MIN(data2) AS data2 
FROM cache 
GROUP BY object_id ;
```

If you have an index on `(object_id, data2)` this will not be too bad in recent versions of Postgres that can use index-only-scan for the execution plan.

---

Another way would be using `DISTINCT ON` syntax. The same index as above would help:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (object_id)
    object_id, data2 
FROM cache 
ORDER BY object_id ;
```

---

If, compared to the table size, there is a small number of `object_id` values, a different approach would be much more efficient. Provided you also have another tables (say `objects`) that has `object_id` as its primary key:

```
SELECT o.object_id, c.data2 
FROM objects AS o
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL 
     ( SELECT data2
       FROM cache AS c 
       WHERE c.object_id = o.object_id
       ORDER BY c.data2 
       LIMIT 1
     ) AS c ;
```

The same index would be needed. The `ORDER BY` is not required but with the index in place, it won't hurt efficiency. If you don't have an `objects` table then that part would have to be replaced with:

```
---
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT object_id FROM cache) AS o
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL 
---
```

But you'd lose some efficiency, especially in older versions. In that case, you could replace this subquery with a complicated recursive query that traverses the `object_id` index efficiently. See the Posgres docs for more details: [Loose Index Scan](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Loose_indexscan).

Read also these great answers by Erwin in the related questions:

- [How do I efficiently get “the most recent corresponding row”?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49540/how-do-i-efficiently-get-the-most-recent-corresponding-row/49555#49555).
- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)
- [Best performance in sampling repeated value from a grouped column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36134657/best-performance-in-sampling-repeated-value-from-a-grouped-column)

---

And last but not least, the main reason for the problems is this:

> I have **denormalized** data and I want to avoid ... (I know that all values in that group are equal booleans).

Normalizing the table would lead to much more efficient queries.

Answer (score 5):

I've stepped the same problem few times but StackExchange was no help to me. You can create a [user defined aggregation function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/sql-createaggregate.html).

Such function will be run over the rows in a group. At minimum you need to present an aggregation function. In my example it's `func_first_value`.

The functions below are `variadic argument type` functions as they work on any types which Postgres can deduce. Default value is `NULL`. I've added prefixes so it's easy to drop them if necessary.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_first_value(v0 anyelement, v1 anyelement) RETURNS anyelement AS $$
BEGIN
    IF v0 IS NOT NULL THEN
        RETURN v0;
    END IF;
    RETURN v1;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- test function
SELECT func_first_value('text'::VARCHAR, NULL), func_first_value(NULL::VARCHAR, NULL), func_first_value(NULL, 'text'::VARCHAR);

CREATE AGGREGATE agg_first_value (anyelement)
(
    sfunc = func_first_value,
    stype = anyelement
);
```

In your case you would need to query:

```
SELECT object_id, agg_first_value(data2) FROM cache GROUP BY object_id;
```

To avoid scanning all values one would need to provide `SORTOP` or `sort_operator` as the Postgres documentation name it. I didn't found *any* example how to use it. Also writing own aggregate function was a lot slower (~6x) than using `MIN` or `MAX` built-in SQL aggregates.

Comment: perfect solution

Comment: I found out how the `SORTOP` is used, but you can't prevent scanning of all the values with it. Based on your answer, you can create a new operator like this:

`create operator >?< (procedure = func_first_value, leftarg = anyelement, rightarg = anyelement);`

And then add it to the create aggregate call:

`create or replace AGGREGATE agg_first_value (anyelement) (sfunc = func_first_value, stype = anyelement, sortop = >?<);`

But no dice, using `explain analyze` on a query with this aggregate still yields a SORT over all values.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one attempt:

```
SELECT distinct object_id
     , first_value(data2) over (partition by object_id) 
FROM cache
```

first_value will work for - almost - any type.

Comment: You'd need `SELECT DISTINCT` so not to return duplicate results, with this query.

Comment: You're right, I skimmed through the constraints. I'll add that to my answer  (tempting to remove the answer since it will likely not be as efficient as the OP wants).

Answer (score 1):

Starting from PostgreSQL 16 there's an `any_value` [aggregate function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/functions-aggregate.html) that you can use. If you want the first or last value in the group, there are some proposed implementations in simple SQL [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/First/last_(aggregate)).

Comment: Please post the full solution here